# Split an Option[String] into (Option[String], Option[String])

Tags: string, scala

For a normal String I am be able to do like this:

```
val str = "asdzxc"
val (first, second) = str.splitAt(3) // splits into ("asd", "zxc")
```

I'd like to be able to do a similar thing for an `Option[String]`:

```
val optionalString: Option[String] = getOptionalString(...)
val (firstOption, secondOption) = ???
```

So that the types of `firstOption` and `secondOption` would be `Option[String]`. I know I can do like this:

```
optionalString.map(_.splitAt(3))
```

which returns me an `Option[(String, String)]` but that is not what I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that in Scalaz this is called `unfzip`, and you can get what you want by writing `optionalString.map(_.splitAt(3)).unfzip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a fold:

```
optionalString.map(_.splitAt(3)).fold((None: Option[String], None: Option[String])) { case (a, b) => (Some(a), Some(b)) }
```

Or pattern matching (possibly a bit clearer since it doesn't need the explicit type parameters):

```
optionalString.map(_.splitAt(3)) match {
  case None => (None,None)
  case Some((a,b)) => (Some(a), Some(b))
}
```